# I am getting an error : rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'CSRFCheck' object has no attribute 'process_request'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from .views import home 
from posts.views import PostListView 

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'), 
    url(r'^post/', include('posts.urls', namespace='post')), 
    url(r'^api/post/', include('posts.api.urls', namespace='post-api')), 
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics

from posts.models import Post
from .serializers import PostModelSerializer

class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from posts.models import Post

class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        field = [
            'user',
            'content'
        ]
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
# from django.contrib import admin

# from django.conf import settings
# from django.conf.urls.static import static
# from .views import home

from .views import PostListAPIView
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    # url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    # url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'), #/api/tweet
    # url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    # url(r'^create/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import home
from posts.views import PostListView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^post/', include('posts.urls',  namespace='post')),
    url(r'^api/post/', include('posts.api.urls',  namespace='post-api')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: I met the same challenge having upgraded to django 1.11.6, while using rest_framework 3.9.1. But this didn't wash my problems away. I suggested a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723230/10849438

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The docs state that Django Rest Framework [works with Django versions 1.11, 2.0, 2.1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements), although the `process_request()` method of `CSRFCheck` was actually introduced in Django **1.11.6**

The version of Django you're using (1.10.3) is too old for your version of Django Rest Framework.

You should upgrade Django to version **1.11.6 or ideally higher**.

```
pip install --upgrade django  # Upgrade to the latest Django version
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade django==1.11.6  # Upgrade to version 1.11.6
```

Comment: Upgrading to 1.11.16 fixed the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't mind upgrading Django, but I need to know why suddenly I see this error. Before now it was working with 1.10. Besides my production version is working ok, the problem I see is in my local environment.