# Django 'CSRFCheck' object has no attribute 'process_request'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It was all ok till suddenly I got the above error while implementing `DjangoObjectPermissions` on my APIs.

Before this It was working ok even my production environment it is working fine. I am seeing this error on my local environment only.

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53499711/1936024) answer, the error would go away, but I need to know why?

Please let me know what information should I add to this post.

Following are the related packages installed.

```
Django==1.10
django-allauth==0.29.0
django-angular==0.8.3
django-debug-toolbar==1.6
django-debug-toolbar-request-history==0.0.3
django-debug-toolbar-template-profiler==1.0.1
django-debug-toolbar-template-timings==0.7
djangorestframework==3.5.3
```

Comment: Probably `DjangoObjectPermissions` tries to call `CSRFCheck.process_request` somewhere. It should be in the error traceback.

Comment: actually, the link I refer above, tells `DRF > 3.5.3` with `Django < 1.11.5` causes this error. I figured out when I was Implementing `DjangoObjectPermissions`, I installed `django-rest-swagger`  which is dependent on `DRF > 3.9.5` and my `DRF` got upgraded to `3.9.5` and thus the above error.

Answer (score 0):

[Add try/except statement to enforce_csrf()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUXjb.png)

Note that this error originates from rest_framework/authentication.py, within class SessionAuthentication, method enforce_csrf(). The enforce_csrf() method iinitiates variable, check = CSRFCheck(), and the next line says "check.process_request(request).

If using an IDE, you'll quickly notice that CSRFCheck() doesn't have this attribute/method thus the error. Many developers will quickly tell you to upgrade to django >= 1.11.6 but you are bound to run into the same error. 
For that matter, am using django 1.11.6 and rest_framework 3.9.1.

So try this remedy, it worked for me. Use the try/except statement.
Go within the rest_framework/authentication.py, below, check = CSRFCheck(), 
add this...

```
def enforce_csrf(self, request):
   ...
   try:
       check.process_request(request)
   except:
       pass
```

What the lines say is this:
After declaring the "check" variable, call (try) this method "process_request()" and if it does not work (except), just pass. You achieve two things with this: One, you literally leave the rest_framework source code compatible (given that upgrading to further versions of django "might" solve this), and two, you get working code (nice!!, especially if working Agile)